# Annual payment of money lent

Tags: arithmetic

What annual payment will discharge a debt of $\$770$ due in 5 years, the rate of interest being $5\%$ per annum?
What I am doing is $(5\% \text{ of } \$770 ) + (\$770 / 5) = \text{ annual payment}$.
The book which I am referring to gives $\$140$ as the answer. How would that be?

Comment: I think the problem is worded poorly.  The $770$ is the forward value of the debt?  If so then you are looking for $P$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^4 P\times (1+.05)^i=770$ which yields $P=\frac {770}{\sum_{i=0}^4 (1+.05)^i}=139.351$ which I guess you could round to $140$.

Comment: At 5% interest per annum, the present value of 5 annual payments of $\$140$ beginning in one year is $\$606$, so @lulu must have the correct interpretation.

Comment: Thank you guys for commenting. @lulu, I did not get how you ended up here. Could you please explain in simplest words? I am beginner in mathematics. What I interpreted is this: 770 is lent. On that 5% interest is there per annum. So, per year one has to pay 154 (770/5) + 38.5 (5% of 770) = $192.5

Comment: Ok.  Because you told me that the official answer was $140$ I looked for an interpretation that gave me that answer, or at least close to it.  Best I could come up with was:  The debt I owe is $770$ payable in $5$ years.  That means, to discharge the debt I just have to pay exactly $770$ five years from today.  To discharge the debt I intend to pay $P$ every year from now till then.  Note that the $P$ I pay in year $5$ will be worth exactly $P$ in year $5$ (obviously).  The $P$ I pay in year $4$ will be worth $1.05P$ in year $5$ and so on.  Hence my formula, which yields $P=139.351$.

Comment: If you want to get to $\$140$ exactly, use simple interest: the first $\$140$ paid at the end of the first year accrues $5\%$ i.e. $\$7$ a year for the remaining $4$ years, and similarly the other payments of  $\$140$ so after five years you end up with $\$140 \times 5 +\$7 \times (4+3+2+1+0) = \$770$ with which to pay off the debt.  The real world does not work like this